# pytesseract output is so weird without any error

Tags: python, tesseract

[image]

```
import pytesseract

from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFilter

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"
im = Image.open("C:\\1.png") # the second one 
im = im.filter(ImageFilter.MedianFilter())
enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(im)
im = enhancer.enhance(2)
im = im.convert('1')
im.save('temp2.png')
#im.show()
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('temp2.png'),config='-psm 8')
print(text)
```

Hi to all

I'm trying to extract text from image(captcha) so it's the code above i'am coding so far.
I don't think there is any problem so far since there is any error when i run it. but output is so poor.

when i run this it shows nothing but i change -psm 8 to -psm 5, it shows ';«'.

Would you give me some advice to fix it?

Comment: the most important property for captcha is not be read by OCR‌ tools

Comment: Oh really, i didn't know it. but it doesn't matter with this code cuz the image i am trying to convert is not captcha image but general png image file for test.

Comment: image is the problem, post your image to make it possible to help you.

Comment: Okay, i uploaded a pic on the top

Answer (score 0):

It's done.

I changed other pic for test and there was no problem at least for this pic.

but i think this module is too poor.. it will be way better to find other module..